How to hash a password in TMS WEB Core?
I am trying to use the TWebSHAHash from my website using Delphi. I tried using what is on the documentation: https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/components/twebshahash/, but it won't work.

[Error] UserSignUp.pas(509): identifier not found "TSHAHash"

My code is exactly like in that example from the website:
procedure TForm1.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject); async;
var
  sha: TWebSHAHash;
  s: string;
begin
  sha := TWebSHAHash.Create(ehSHA1);
  s := Await(string, sha.Hash('text to be hashed'));
  WebMemo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;


Did you add WEBLIB.Crypto to your uses clause?

That's why I consider every example which doesn't include its uses part as incomplete: you have to guess or rely on your IDE features to find the unit of a type.

@AmigoJack You are so correct. With TMS I use the IDE's  Search then Find in Files and search the TMS source files.

You might want to do a quick web search for "Delphi Uses Helper". It makes it easier than "find in files" all the time.
